# Set Text after retrofit response

Tags: android, textview, retrofit

I am working with retrofit to get some statistics. They arrive at the app. When I try to set some TextView's text to the values they throw a NullPointerException. Is there something I should know?

```
public void init() {
    getStatistics();
txtNrCompleted.setText(String.format("%s", statistics.getTask()));
}

private void getStatistics(){
    endpoints = RetrofitJsonCaller.call(APIEndpoints.class);
    callStatistics = endpoints.getStatistics(URLEndpoints.getStatistics());
    callStatistics.enqueue(new Callback<STATISTIC>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<STATISTIC> call, Response<STATISTIC> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                setStatistics(response.body());

            }else{
                Log.d("STATISTICS", "Error: " + response.code());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<STATISTIC> call, Throwable t) {
            Timber.d(t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}

public void setStatistics(STATISTIC statistics){
    this.statistics = statistics;
}
```

LOGS:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Integer com.example.taskmanagement.model.STATISTIC.getTaskComplet()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.taskmanagement.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:111)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6948)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
```

Comment: Hello, please, provide code and crash log to get more details about your problem

Comment: logs & code please ? Are you sure it is a `NullPointerException` ? Do not forget to update UI only on main thread...

Answer (score 1):

Retrofit is making the call to get the statistics asynchronously, but you are setting the text in the `TextView` synchronously. You call `getStatistics()` which triggers the call to get the new statistics but doesn't wait for it to finish. You then set the text immediately after, at which point the `statistics` object is still null. You need to update the `TextView` after you get a successful response. For example:

```
public void init() {
    getStatistics(); 
}

private void getStatistics() {
    ...
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<STATISTIC> call, Response<STATISTIC> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                setStatistics(response.body()); 
                // Call the code to update your UI here, as we have now received the stats
                updateUI(); 
            } else {
                ...
            }
        }
    ...
}

...

private void updateUI() {
    textNrCompleted.setText(String.format("%s", statistics.getTask())); 
}
```